# Does the sequence of partial sums converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n { \frac{2}{3^k}}$

I am confused. Can I turn it into a limit approaching infinity even though $n$ is there? There was a previous question that asked me to find the first four terms of the sequence so does that mean $n = 4$? I need help please.

Comment: First, what is the question?

Comment: Does the sequence of partial sums converge or diverge?

Comment: You are restating the question, but what does it **mean**.  Define **partial sums** for example

Answer (score 1):

One may recall the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) result (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) also)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=x \cdot\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad x \neq1,
$$ giving
$$
S_n = 2\sum_{k=1}^n { \frac{1}{3^k}}=\frac{2}{3} \cdot\frac{1-1/3^{n}}{1-1/3}
$$ then, as $n \to \infty$, since $1/3^n \to 0$, one gets
$$
S_n \to \frac{2}{3} \cdot\frac{1}{1-1/3}=1.
$$

Comment: Goodness, I'm trying to teach someone XD